# Inserir os registros que só existem na tabela de origem com MERGE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Criei o script abaixo que só faz a inserção somente dos registros que não existem na tabela `teste_tb_planos_acoes`, coloquei algumas condições:

Caso o valor da coluna `designacao` exista na tabela `teste_tb_planos_acoes` e a coluna `status_fim  = encerrado`, verifique se  a coluna `data_fim` é maior que `>=30` dias e faça update no registro atualizando as colunas:

```
status_fim = aberto

Prazo = getdate()+2
```

Porém preciso colocar mais um critério, que eu não estou conseguindo:
Quando não há o `MATCHED`, mesmo existindo o valor na tabela `teste_tb_planos_acoes` verifique se `DATEDIFF(DAY, b.data_fim, GETDATE()) > 45)`, se for maior, permitir inserir o registro, caso contrário não inserir.
Segue o script:

```
MERGE teste_tb_planos_acoes AS T
USING
(
SELECT distinct
    A.designacao, 
    A.Cliente,
    desc_uds,
    A.qtde_log,
    A.rec_ano,
    B.designacao AS designacao_B
FROM tb_calcula_hist_log A
LEFT JOIN teste_tb_planos_acoes B ON A.designacao = B.designacao
WHERE
    (B.designacao IS NULL) OR
    (B.status_fim = 'encerrado' and  b.data_fim between dateadd(day, -45, cast( current_timestamp as date)) and dateadd(day, -10, cast( current_timestamp as date)))) AS U
ON U.designacao = T.designacao AND U.designacao_B IS NOT NULL
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET status_fim = 'aberto', prazo = GETDATE() + 2, qtde_log = U.qtde_log, reaberto = 'sim'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT
(
    designacao,
    cliente,
    area,
    qtde_log,
    data_cad,
    data_email_env,
    login_cadastro,
    rec_num,
    status_fim,
    prazo
)
VALUES
(
U.designacao, 
U.Cliente,
U.desc_uds,
U.qtde_log,
GETDATE(),
GETDATE(),
'w7spo082851\GEO',
U.rec_ano,
'aberto',
GETDATE() + 2
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado ! Um colega em outro fórum conseguiu me ajudar.

```
   MERGE teste_tb_planos_acoes AS T
 USING
(
   SELECT distinct
    A.designacao, 
    A.Cliente,
    desc_uds,
    A.qtde_log,
    A.rec_ano,
    O.data_fim,
    O.dif_dias
FROM tb_calcula_hist_log A
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP(1)
        B.data_fim,
        B.status_fim,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, B.data_fim, GETDATE()) as dif_dias
    FROM teste_tb_planos_acoes B 
    WHERE 
        B.designacao = A.designacao
    ORDER BY
        B.data_fim 
   ) O    
   WHERE
    (O.status_fim IS NULL) OR
    ((O.status_fim = 'encerrado') and
     (O.dif_dias between 10 and 30 or O.dif_dias > 45) and
     (not exists
         (select 1 from teste_tb_planos_acoes E
          where
              E.designacao = A.designacao and
              E.status_fim = 'aberto')))
         ) AS U
           ON 
             U.designacao = T.designacao AND
             U.data_fim = T.data_fim AND
             U.dif_dias between 10 and 30
          WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE  SET status_fim = 'aberto', prazo = GETDATE() + 2, qtde_log = 
   U.qtde_log, reaberto = 'sim'
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT
(
    designacao,
    cliente,
    area,
    qtde_log,
    data_cad,
    data_email_env,
    login_cadastro,
    rec_num,
    status_fim,
    prazo
   )
    VALUES
  (
    U.designacao, 
    U.Cliente,
    U.desc_uds,
    U.qtde_log,
    GETDATE(),
    GETDATE(),
    'w7spo082851\GEO',
    U.rec_ano,
    'aberto',
    GETDATE() + 2
);
```

Comment: @Evaldo, o seu problema era inseri ou atualizar a tabela dependendo do critério. Não estou vendo isso aqui neste seu post. De qualquer forma, o mais importante é você ter resolvido seu problema.

Comment: Havia postado apenas uma parte do código, atualizei a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que tem retirar as condições da query inicial e colocar as suas condições como colunas. Assim vai fazer MATCH sempre que existir registo (independente das restantes condições) mas assim você vai poder colocar esses critérios no momento do MATCH. Algo como isto:

```
MERGE teste_tb_planos_acoes AS T
USING
(
SELECT distinct
    A.designacao, 
    A.Cliente,
    desc_uds,
    A.qtde_log,
    A.rec_ano,
    B.designacao AS designacao_B,
    CASE WHEN B.designacao IS NOT NULL AND 
                B.status_fim = 'encerrado' AND  
                b.data_fim between dateadd(day, -45, cast( current_timestamp as date)) and 
                dateadd(day, -10, cast( current_timestamp as date)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as CanUpdate,
    CASE WHEN B.designacao IS NOT NULL AND DATEDIFF(DAY, b.data_fim, GETDATE()) > 45) as CanInsert
FROM tb_calcula_hist_log A
LEFT JOIN teste_tb_planos_acoes B ON A.designacao = B.designacao) AS U
     ON U.designacao = T.designacao AND U.designacao_B IS NOT NULL
WHEN MATCHED AND U.CanUpdate = 1 THEN
    UPDATE SET status_fim = 'aberto', prazo = GETDATE() + 2, qtde_log = U.qtde_log, reaberto = 'sim'
WHEN MATCHED AND U.CanInsert = 1 THEN
    INSERT
    (
        designacao,
        cliente,
        area,
        qtde_log,
        data_cad,
        data_email_env,
        login_cadastro,
        rec_num,
        status_fim,
        prazo
    )
    VALUES
    (
    U.designacao, 
    U.Cliente,
    U.desc_uds,
    U.qtde_log,
    GETDATE(),
    GETDATE(),
    'w7spo082851\GEO',
    U.rec_ano,
    'aberto',
    GETDATE() + 2
    );
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT
(
    designacao,
    cliente,
    area,
    qtde_log,
    data_cad,
    data_email_env,
    login_cadastro,
    rec_num,
    status_fim,
    prazo
)
VALUES
(
U.designacao, 
U.Cliente,
U.desc_uds,
U.qtde_log,
GETDATE(),
GETDATE(),
'w7spo082851\GEO',
U.rec_ano,
'aberto',
GETDATE() + 2
);
```